# Deserializing JSON data in Mono

Tags: c#, json, mono, deserialization

Is there an easy way to deserialize a simple JSON string into a .NET object when using Monodroid? System.Json only provides serialization (no deserialization) and the various third party libs I've tried were all causing problems with Mono/Monodroid.
Thank you.

Comment: Have ou looked at the JavaScriptSerializer class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Comment: Yeah, that requires an assembly which was not available. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fastJSON suits the bill. Grab the required files (Getters.cs, JSON.cs, JsonParser.cs, JsonSerializer.cs, SafeDictionary.cs) and embed them in your project and use it. It doesn't use any fancy .NET specific class so it should work with MonoDroid or Silverlight.

Comment: No problem. I'm currently using only the JsonSerializer.cs part in one of my projects, which is working well for me.

Comment: Mono Android 2.2 Can't use Newtonsoft.Json , You solve my problem!