# System.Runtime.Serialization.Json in Monodroid?

Tags: .net, serialization, .net-4.0, xamarin.android

I am wondering if anyone knows if I can use "System.Runtime.Serialization.Json (4.0)" in monodroid.

I only see "System.Runtime.Serialization (2.0.5)" in the assemblies of monodroid. This does not contain ".Json".

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `System.Json` namespace in monodroid. Also see: [Deserializing JSON data in Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997288/deserializing-json-data-in-mono)

Comment: hmm I was looking at it but it does not have "DataContractJsonSerializer" which is what a port of a windows 7 phone has. Guess I have to write a different way to do it.

Comment: @chobo2: Mono for Android provides System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer in System.ServiceModel.Web.dll, same as Silverlight and Windows Phone 7 do. Same type, same namespace, same assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I use the MonoDroid version of JSON.NET and it works perfectly.

https://github.com/ayoung/Newtonsoft.Json